# jQuery - Sorting Parent Div with children div values not working

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an array with 2 values, 'Rank' and 'Parameter', which I'm looping to create multiple Divs within a parent Div.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
var BrandArray = {
    "Brand1" : [{"Parameter":"XXX", "Rank":"#3"}],
    "Brand2" : [{"Parameter":"AAA", "Rank":"#2"}],
    "Brand3" : [{"Parameter":"MMM", "Rank":"#1"}],
}

var markup = '';
BrandArrayKeys = Object.keys(BrandArray)
jQuery.each(BrandArrayKeys, function(index, value){
    markup +=  '<div id="BrandBlock">'
    markup +=  '<div>' + BrandArray[value][0].Rank + '</div>'
    markup +=  '<div>' + BrandArray[value][0].Parameter + '</div>'
    markup +=  '</div>'    
});
$("#list").html(markup);
});
```

I'm then using a sort function after this to ensure that it appears sorted on Rank

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var sortedList = $('#BrandBlock').toArray().sort(function(lhs, rhs){ 
      return $(lhs).find("#Rank").text().replace( /^\D+/g, '') - $(rhs).find("#Rank").text().replace( /^\D+/g, ''); 
   });
   console.log(sortedList)
    $("#list").empty().html(sortedList);
});
```

This isnt working and only one 'Div' appears in the page. This formula however works when the DIV Table already resides in the HTML itself instead of being built by jQuery.

Where am I going wrong?

Find below the entire working code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var BrandArray = {
    "Brand1": [{
      "Parameter": "XXX",
      "Rank": "#3"
    }],
    "Brand2": [{
      "Parameter": "AAA",
      "Rank": "#2"
    }],
    "Brand3": [{
      "Parameter": "MMM",
      "Rank": "#1"
    }],
  }

  var markup = '';
  BrandArrayKeys = Object.keys(BrandArray)
  jQuery.each(BrandArrayKeys, function(index, value) {
    markup += '<div id="BrandBlock">'
    markup += '<div>' + BrandArray[value][0].Rank + '</div>'
    markup += '<div>' + BrandArray[value][0].Parameter + '</div>'
    markup += '</div>'
  });
  $("#list").html(markup);
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var sortedList = $('#BrandBlock').toArray().sort(function(lhs, rhs) {
    return $(lhs).find("#Rank").text().replace(/^\D+/g, '') - $(rhs).find("#Rank").text().replace(/^\D+/g, '');
  });
  $("#list").empty().html(sortedList);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="list"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of issues here. Firstly because you're appending an element with the same `id` multiple times. `id` attributes *have to be unique* within the DOM. This needs to be changed to a class.

Secondly, your sort logic expects there to be an element within each `#BrandBlock` with an id of `Rank`, however this does not exist and if it did you would again be repeating identifiers and causing the same issue. Change the logic to sort by the class, and add the class in to the HTML.

With those fixes in place, the code works. Note that I also made it more succinct by using `map()`, `Object.entries()` and some arrow functions.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let brandArray = {Brand1:[{Parameter:"XXX",Rank:"#3"}],Brand2:[{Parameter:"AAA",Rank:"#2"}],Brand3:[{Parameter:"MMM",Rank:"#1"}]};
  
  let markup = Object.entries(brandArray).map(([key, obj]) => `<div class="brandblock"><div class="rank">${obj[0].Rank}</div><div>${obj[0].Parameter}</div></div>`);
  $("#list").html(markup);

  var sortedList = $('.brandblock').sort((lhs, rhs) => $(lhs).find(".rank").text().replace(/^\D+/g, '') - $(rhs).find(".rank").text().replace(/^\D+/g, ''));
  $("#list").html(sortedList);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="list"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @Rory McCrossan. Just curious, why doesn't it work whn i replace ID with class in my formula? `var markup = ''; brandArrayKeys = Object.keys(brandArray) jQuery.each(brandArrayKeys, function(index, value){ markup +=  '<div class="brandblock">'markup +=  '<div class="rank">' + brandArray[value][0].Rank + '</div>'markup +=  '<div class="rank">' + brandArray[value][0].Parameter + '</div>'markup +=  '</div>'}); $("#list").html(markup);`